# "@Constructor not applicable to constructor" while trying to annotate constructor with jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations.Constructor

Tags: java, intellij-idea, constructor, getter-setter

When I try to use annotation `jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations.Constructor` on constructor of my class I get compilation error saying:

> @Constructor not applicable to constructor

Screenshot from IntelliJ:

[image]

Does anyone know the reason that it's showing me this error?

Simplified code:

```
package passengers;

import jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations.Constructor;
import jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.annotations.Getter;

public class Passenger {

    private String name;
    private Stop destination;

    @Constructor //<-- here I see: @Constructor not applicable to constructor
    public Passenger(String name) {
        //..
    }

    @Getter  //<- this works fine
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because the undocumented, internal `Constructor` annotation that you're using is only applicable to methods, not constructors. It's annotated with `@Target({ElementType.METHOD})`.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. Then is there a way to annotate constructors or do we just leave them be?

Comment: I have no idea of what these annotations are. They're part of an undocumented, internal package, so you should probably not use them.

Comment: @JBNizet there is bit of documentation. See answer or https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_nashorn/blob/master/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/objects/annotations/Constructor.java

Comment: @JasonHoward ultimately, if you need a JS constructor for your Passenger class, you need to use a method.

Answer (score 1):

IDEA is absolutely correct on that.

When you encounter such situations, first thing you should do is look at the `@Constructor` annotation JavaDoc or [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_nashorn/blob/master/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/objects/annotations/Constructor.java). What you'd see is

```
/**
 * Specifies a specific method to be the JavaScript "constructor" function.
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Constructor { ... }
```

This

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
```

means the annotation can be specified on methods.
If it was compatible with constructors, you'd have found

```
@Target({ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.METHOD})
```

---

Anyway this comes from an `internal` package, so you probably shouldn't use it.